# Android loadout/layout-land onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, android-layout, dialogfragment, android-configchanges

I have a DialogFragment in my Android app, and I need to set `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize`, I want to load different layout for my DialogFragment in portrait or landscape, but now Android will not automatically do this for me, I think I need to update the layout in `onConfigurationChanged` , but I don't know how to do it, any sample code will be better, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another most common solution to dealing with orientation changes by setting the android:configChanges flag on your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml. Using this attribute your Activities won’t be recreated and all your views and data will still be there after orientation change.

**try this code and changed your configuration :**

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.test.activity.MainActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

This attribute informs to Android system that you are going to handle orientation and screenSize changes for this Activity. So instead of destroying and recreating your Activity, Android will just rotate the screen and invoke one of the lifecycle callback method which is onConfigurationChanged(Configuration).

**try this**

Answer (score 0):

I finnally find my solution, but I think it maybe only work for my situation, my situation is I want to show a imageView in portrait and not show in landscape, so I set the visibility as visiable or gone in function `onConfigurationChanged'` and it works